# What count(predicate) is doing in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I was surprised to see one of my students writing

```
select count(title='Staff') from titles
```

against MySQL employees database. Does it mean to be a nice shortcut for

```
select sum(case when title='Staff' then 1 else 0 end) from titles
```

which just fails to work in MySQL 5.6 (returning full table count)?

Comment: did you ask the student? did you try it out to see if it actually works?

Comment: It is syntactically correct, but returns table cardinality as I have wrote already.

Comment: "which just fails to work in MySQL 5.6 (returning full table count)?" what about rows with `null` value? Does it count them? AFAIK - it shouldn't.

Comment: This question is in the context of database introductory class. There null values play secondary role. I'm more concerned with students failing to grasp concept of selection (restriction) operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this `count` is not a shorthand for the `sum` you wrote.

`COUNT(exp)` counts the number of rows with a **not null `exp`**.
`title='Staff'` is a Boolean expression, which evaluates to `true` if title is 'Staff', `false` if it's any other value or `null` if it's null.

So, this query is equivalent to

```
select count(title) from titles
```

which, in turn, is equivalent to

```
select count(*) from titles where title is not null
```

Comment: OK, then it is just useless syntax which is meant to confuse people. No wonder other RDBMSs not allow it. (My personal opinion is that count shouldn't have any arguments at all).

Comment: @TegiriNenashi: You can pass `COUNT` the field you want it to "count".  Check this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de0b3/1  `COUNT(*)` will return all rows found, whereas `COUNT(title)` will return all rows with a non-null title.  If you are adding `where title is not null` to your query, then `COUNT(*)` is fine, but without a `where` clause, you may get different results.

Comment: @TegiriNenashi Actually, `COUNT(exp)` is part of ANSI SQL. As to the usefulness/uselessness of it - I guess it's in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Again, I understand syntax, but I don't agree it achieves anything. "select count(title='Staff'), count(title='Programmer'), count(title is not null) from titles" would be less confusing and more expressive.

Answer (score 1):

**No**!
You can't count against an condition write into brackets. It simple return all rows from that table.

`select count(title='Staff') from titles`
return all rows from `titles`

Comment: Close, but it will actually return all rows `WHERE title IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Yes, @Mureinik answer it's very good and complete. It gives me also a better understanding of how mysql count function works.